# JavaScript enumeration

Tags: javascript, enumeration

I have a file [not a .js file] that has a list of errors mapped with error codes in the following format.

```
    404  = The requested resource could not be found
    500  = Internal server error
    1001 = No message body found
    1002 = No message header found
```

and so on....[about 3000 lines.]

I wish to write a function, pass the error code as parameter and expect to receive the corresponding string as errorString.

I am using Javascript for my web app. But unfortunately, the file that contains the error list in this format.
C an anybody suggest what I should do to get the work done.

I am also ready to convert this file to a java script file, if any body can suggest how would I achieve that for about 3000 lines of code.

Thank you.

Comment: I would also expect if the format can be converted to : 
Constants = {

      404: function(){
      return "XYZ Error";
    },
    500: function(){
      return "MNX Error";
    },
};

Comment: Use an editor that supports search/replace by regular expression. Should take all of 30 seconds to turn this into JSON. In vim, I would use `:%s/\s\+= /": "/` and `:%s/^/"` and `:%s/$/",`, and then add `{` to the beginning and `}` to the end. We're not going to convert it for you, you're going to have to do that work yourself.

Comment: @meagar regexps are overkill, every code editor I know supports *Modify Lines*, *Wrap Lines* or a similarly named basic function. Heck, [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) even supports it.

Comment: @meagar: Wanted to write exactly the same. +1

Comment: @meager : How would I write the expression, to convert the line 
1 = If request list is null

to

1 : function(){
      return "If request list is null";
    },

I swear I tried , I failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am also ready to convert this file to a java script file, if any body can suggest how would I
>   achieve that for about 3000 lines of code.

Using any editor worth its salt you can just append `",` to every line, and replace `=` with `:"`. This would give you:

```
404: "The requested resource could not be found",
500: "Internal server error",
1001: "No message body found",
1002: "No message header found",
```

Then replace the last comma in the file with `};`, and add `var myObject = {` in the beginning, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change file type or content, you can try to parse it and fit it in a dict at load event of your page, this way you create dict once and will be available for all your functions

```
var url='URL-TO-YOUR-FILE'
messages = {} //global scope, messages will be available for all your functions
parse_messages().done(function(r) {
    messages = r
})
.fail(function(x) {
    //messages doesn't load well, show the error
    console.log(x)
});


function parse_messages(){
    return $.get(url, function(html){
        lines = html.split(/\n/)
        lines.forEach(function(line){
            var splitted_line = line.split("=")
            if (splitted_line && splitted_line.length == 2){
                var code = splitted_line[0].trim()
                //check if code is valid
                if(!isNaN(code)){
                    messages[code] = splitted_line[1].trim()
                }
            }   
        })
    })
}
```

Here is the output

```
>>>> messages
>>>> Object {404: "The requested resource could not be found", 500: "Internal server error", 1001: "No message body found", 1002: "No message header foundvar codes;"}
```

Comment: The problem here is that it makes an unnecessary request every single time. Also, it takes processing power (ok, very little but still) when it is not needed.

Comment: while list is and external file, always will be an extra request

Comment: even if it's loaded as json or jsonp, there will be an extra request, i don't understand you @Charleshaa

Comment: Well you could put it as a string in variable then, since it does exactly that when you do a `$.get()`.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought you would put that as a function's body, but you actually mean to put this code on load to create the object on the fly right ?

Comment: I use an string varible (html) and its content comes from an external file, like requirements says. I don't agree with your downvote

Comment: Yes, mea culpa, I jumped too quickly, I'll remove the downvote :), just do an edit so I can remove it

Comment: Neither `lines` nor `messages` should be global variables, they're the result of an asynchronous call. Use a promise!

Comment: I mean a promise *for* the messages, not a promise that notifies when they're ready. Your variables are still global, and with the change your code doesn't even work any more - `parse_messages()` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score -2):

Do what Niels or meagar said, then get your file using (jquery)

```
var codes;
$.get(FILEURL, function(res){ codes = res; });

function getMessageFromCode(code){
  return codes[code];
}
```

Or, simply use `codes[500]`, a function is really not needed there.

**EDIT**

If you need it to be synchronous, **which would be wise**, then just include the file (after having made the edits suggested by Niels) in your `<head>`. You'll be able to to use `myObject[500]` then.

Comment: [You can't make an async `$.get` synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: You've introduced a bug where sometimes, `getMessageFromCode(500)` will return a string, and sometimes it will raise an error about `codes` being undefined.